# How do I compare List<List<int>> to exist in other List<List<int>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know in Flutter if my sequence exists in the other `sequenceTwo`. For the example, I made two identical `List<List<int>>` that work. But I also want to know if it exists even if there are more record before or after the sequence as in the next check I do in the code below.

```
List<List<int>> sequence = [];
sequence.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 6, 63, 13, 10]));
sequence.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 9, 66, 13, 10]));
sequence.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 0, 57, 13, 10]));
sequence.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 3, 60, 13, 10]));

List<List<int>> sequenceTwo = [];
sequenceTwo.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 6, 63, 13, 10]));
sequenceTwo.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 9, 66, 13, 10]));
sequenceTwo.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 0, 57, 13, 10]));
sequenceTwo.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 8, 3, 60, 13, 10]));

Function deepEqOne = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals;
debugPrint(
    'DeepCollection: ' + deepEqOne(sequence, sequenceTwo).toString()); // true so works!

sequenceTwo.add(Uint8List.fromList([42, 6, 1, 9, 3, 60, 13, 10]));
debugPrint(
        'DeepCollection: ' + deepEqOne(sequence, sequenceTwo).toString()); // false but I want this also to work somehow
```

Comment: sequenceTwo is still empty in your code snipped, you added everything to sequence - is that just a copy paste error?

Comment: Well spotted. I changed the above question and code snippet a bit so it's more clear what my question now is.